# Multiple Angular selects - changing one value affect the next select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour in the following scenario. A colleciton of selects allows you to configure a list of cars selected(`myCars`) from the list of cars available.

```
<div *ngFor="let car of myCars; let i = index;">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Car</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="myCars[i]" (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event, i)">
            <mat-option>-</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let car of carsAvailable" [value]="car">{{car.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addNewCar()">Add new car</button>
```

The problem is that when I have two cars in my list, for instance:

```
Select1 : Ferrari
Select2 : Ferrari
```

and change the value of the `Select1` to `Audi`, both selects are incorrectly set to that value:

```
Select1 : Audi
Select2 : Audi
```

however myCars array contains `[Ferrari, Audi]`, which is correct.
Interestingly if I pick Audi in `select2` instead, `select1` would remain unchanged. And even if I had 10 identical selects with Ferrari selected and changed i-th select to Audi, only the i+1th would change to Audi as well.

Does any of you have an explanation of why this might be happening? To me it looks like some sort of a race condition, where the DOM item corresponding to the i-th select gets removed first and Angular sets the i+1th select because it matches it by the object reference.

Here's an example of the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74wwjj?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts

Comment: Could you share stackblitz?

Comment: I have a guess. U r using two way databinding with [(value)] and are triggering in selection changed event to set the car manually although u already Bound the myCars[i] to the value. I would try leaving out the selection chabged event and just log on the callback your mycars List. Regards

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74wwjj?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts

Comment: @user4205580 Have you solved this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reason for current behaviour:**

Consider initially you have list as:

```
1. Ferrari
2. Ferrari
3. Ferrari
```

Here, 1,2,3 indexes are mentioned just for explanation purpose. Actually they are the same objects.

Now, when you change the first dropdown to `Audi`, the new list becomes:

```
Audi
1. Ferrari
2. Ferrari
```

Why it is becoming like this instead of below is explained in below table.

```
Audi
2. Ferrari
3. Ferrari
```

Internally angular maintains a linked list for items. So in below table New List Items' Next and Prev links are mentioned. To understand the table, read it row by row. Though in actual code the linked list changes and DOM updates are happeing separately, to keep it simple, I have combined them in below explanation.

```
Old List    | New List    | New List prev    | New List next     | Description
1.Ferrari   | Audi        | null             | 1.Ferrari         | As Audi is new object, it will create new DOM node for this item and attaches it at 0 index. It will detach the 1.Ferrari object from index: 0.
2.Ferrari   | 1.Ferrari   | Audi             | 2.Ferrari         | It first checks if Ferrari object exists in detached list. In this case it does exist. So, it will re-attach the detached 1.Ferrari object at index: 1
3.Ferrari   | 2.Ferrari   | 1.Ferrari        | 3.Ferrari         | It checks if Ferrari exists in detached list. In this case it doesn't. So, it will attach the 2.Ferrari at index: 2.
```

Now, Next item to last item in the list (2.Ferrari) is 3.Ferrari. As length of the new list should be 3, it will truncate the list and discard the 3.Ferrari.

So, if you again check the demo you shared, you can see that it feels like focus is shifted to second item when we change value of first dropdown. It feels like so because it is actually just moving our first item DOM to second position. As it is just moving that record and not doing any change detection for that item, the display value below the second dropdown still shows Ferrari.

**Solution:**

You can solve this by setting `trackBy` function. So, instead of tracking items by object references, it can track by return value of the `trackBy` function. In below exmaple, it is tracking item by index.

```
<div *ngFor="let car of myCars; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
</div>
```

```
trackByIndex(index, item) {
 return index;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74wwjj-olzks2

Hope it will help!

Comment: I'm wondering why it always changed only the value of the next select, so for instance initially 3 selects were set to Ferrari, and after changing the first select, both 1st and 2nd got set to Audi, but not 3rd, even though it should get matched according to this explanation. Also the funny thing is that even though the second select gets set to Audi, the div below (I've added a div there inside ngFor that shows the car name) still shows Ferrari. Shouldn't it be replaced as well?:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74wwjj-gdhmdx?file=app/select-value-binding-example.html
even thoigh

Comment: @user4205580, You are correct. Thanks for asking this question. It encouraged me to look inside ngFor directive code and understand it better. I have updated the answer to make it more clear. Hope it helps now :)

Answer (score 1):

You must change your HTML like

```
<div *ngFor="let car of myCars; let i = index;">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Car</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="car" (selectionChange)="selected($event, i)">
            <mat-option>-</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let _car of carsAvailable" [value]="_car">{{_car.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Because, you had two variables which name as car in your DOM. So you must change it. and also you must change your `mat-select`'s value property as car.

Lastly, remove `this.myCars[index] = matSelectChange.value;` line in your `selected` function in ts file.

Example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-74wwjj-ohvfft)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Check the content of myCars array after you added the cars in your example - it contains empty objects, not cars - not what I want.